# nuxt 2: postcss-preset-env: Unknown feature: "customProperties", did you mean: "custom-properties"

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

I've recently had my nuxt project not compiling anymore:

```
WARN  Compiled with 1 warnings

WARN  in /build/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2b6db950&lang=css&

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(1:1) postcss-preset-env: Unknown feature: "customProperties", did you mean: "custom-properties"

@ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!/build/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2b6db950&lang=css& 4:14-352 15:3-20:5 16:22-360
@ /build/components/nuxt-error.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2b6db950&lang=css&
@ /build/components/nuxt-error.vue
@ /build/index.js
@ /build/client.js
@ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2Fmon-espace%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client /build/client.js


ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

This relative module was not found:

* ./index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=a00a9554&scoped=true&lang=scss& in ./pages/my_path/_slug/index.vue
```

Anyone has this error? I have been investigating quite a lot, trying to upgrade dependencies, without success.

Here's my current config:

```
    "nuxt": "^2.16.2",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "vue": "^2.7.14"
```

Comment: did you recently upgrade your nuxt version ? nuxt recently issued a new version and upgraded view to `2.7` which had some breaking changes https://nuxtjs.org/releases/#%EF%B8%8F-breaking-changes:~:text=full%20details%20below-,%E2%9A%A0%EF%B8%8F%20Breaking%20changes,-In%20this%20PR and one of the changes is a new `postcss options format` which I'm suspecting is what you are facing

Comment: I found the error and added an answer to my post. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my bad, I had this config remaining in my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
  build: {
    postcss: {
      preset: {
        features: {
          customProperties: false,
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

which made it fail when I upgraded my nuxt version.

Of course it was not in the main config file but in some sub-imported file otherwise I would have seen it quicker but whatever!